# SSO(Short string optimization) & utf-32 encoding question

Tags: c++, string

I have some questions about strings in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void* operator new(std::size_t count) {
    std::cout << count << " bytes allocation" << std::endl;
    return malloc(count);
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string str1 = "Test string";
    std::cout << str1.size() << " " << str1[5] << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::string str2 = "Test string Test string Test string";
    std::cout << str2.size() << " " << str2[5] << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::u32string u32_str = U"This is UTF-32";
    std::cout << u32_str.size() << " " << u32_str[5] << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then the output of this code is...

```
8 bytes allocation

8 bytes allocation
11 s

8 bytes allocation
48 bytes allocation
35 s

8 bytes allocation
64 bytes allocation
14 105
```

I override `operator new`. I make new operator prints something as you see.

1. `str2` is long string literal, so I understand memory space is needed for `"Test string Test string Test string"`. Also I understand memory space is not needed for short string `str1`. Why do we need eight bytes? Where did the eight bytes come from?
2. The utf32 encoding method processes all characters by 4 bytes. Why is the `size()` result value of `str3` 14 bytes instead of 14 * 4 = 56 bytes?

Comment: `Why is the size() result value of str3 14 bytes instead of 14 * 4 = 56 bytes?` It is not. It is 14 __characters__, not 14 bytes.

Comment: [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) isn't a byte length; it's a character count.

Comment: Not all memory used by this program is allocated with `new`, so you are not logging everything that is being allocated. At the very least, try including the `string.capacity()` value in your logs.

Comment: `The utf8 encoding method processes all characters by 4 bytes.` It does what? And what does utf-8 have to do with this anyway? u32 is not a utf-8 string.

Comment: @tkausl I'm sure the OP meant UTF-32 instead, since `u32` is a UTF-32 string

Comment: If you want to know where "the eight bytes come from", simply set a breakpoint in your overridden `operator new`, and your debugger will hand over this information on a silver platter.

Comment: @WhozCraig In this [page](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) Return Value
is "The number of bytes in the string"

Comment: @user19246061 That is specifically for `std::string`, not `std::basic_string` and its other specializations. See [this](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/size/) page on the same site for the general case. The site is however known to be often out-of-date and sometimes wrong. I suggest you use cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @user19246061 Yes, that site has upgraded so that part looks almost correct. If you want a wiki that is updated when people find errors, try [cpprefrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @user19246061 One of the many, many examples as to why that site is continually referred to as crap info for C++ engineers. Delete it from your browser cache and bookmarks, and use the one I linked. It is pretty-much the de-facto go-to reference for C++ engineers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did with F5, but I just got only information about parameter(count). Is there any more detail debugging way to know where "the eight bytes come from"???

Comment: What compiler and standard library implementation are you using?

Comment: @user17732522 I just use visual studio 2019 with basic setting compiler. I don't know specific name of compiler :( I'm just starting c++

Comment: Minor caution: there is nothing that prohibits stream inserters frmm calling `operator new` and if that happened the result would be an infinite recursion. That’s purely hypothetical; no sane implementation would do that. But if you want to be absolutely safe, use `printf` for the logging in `operator new`.

Comment: @user19246061 Try it in release mode and see whether the eight bytes allocation are still there. I suspect they are just to store some debug information. If you are only just starting to learn the language, I don't know why you would care about all of this though. You don't need to care about what allocations the standard library makes and `u32string` is not that common.

Comment: Every debugger that I know of will show a backtrace. If your debugger doesn't, you should look into switching to a better debugger. For example, with gdb, the `bt` command would show me the entire call chain, and where exactly each function gets called from. I am not familiar with whatever debugger you're using, or what it's F5 does, check your debugger documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That's another instance of the Microsoft compiler being wrong, in this case subtly so. Both [gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/sbPq3Gc7E) implement short string optimisation correctly.

```
11 s

36 bytes allocation
35 s

60 bytes allocation
14 105
```